# Overlay video on top of Image - Do not resize Video, simply create a "larger" canvas around video

Tags: ffmpeg, video, video-editing

Is the following possible with ffmpeg?

Basically I want to leave the original video size alone, just make the video centered over a larger image, so it creates a border effect, as per following:
[image]:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The overlay filter can do the trick:

```
ffmpeg -i background.png -i input.mp4 -filter_complex "overlay=(W-w)/2:(H-h)/2" output.mp4
```

Credit to @llogan for [the answer to the opposite question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10920872/17011606)